# django input serializer date field format

Tags: python, django, django-serializer, datefield

I have a date input format in `mm/dd/yyyy`.

In my input serializer,

```
class ProjectInitSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    client_name = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False, max_length=300)
    file_name = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=False, max_length=300)
    run_date = serializers.DateField(required=True, input_formats="%d/%m/%Y")
```

I get this response:

```
"response": {
    "run_date": [
        "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: %, d, /, %, m, /, %, Y."
    ]
}
```

This serializer is used for input request only.

How do I format this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `input_formats` to a list.

```
run_date = serializers.DateField(required=True, input_formats=["%d/%m/%Y"])
```